# How to convert an array of gsl::byte to a uint64_t value?

Tags: c++, casting, byte, gsl

What is the correct way to convert an array of gsl::byte to its corresponding uint64_t representation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/byte>
#include <array>

int main()
{   
  std::array<gsl::byte, 8> gsl_byte_array{{0x10_gslb,0x12_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb}};

  uint64_t int_value{};

  std::cout << int_value << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just updated the array. I would simply obtain the integer representation. Is memcpy() the only solution?

Comment: No, `memcpy()` is not the only solution. Bit-shifting each byte into the `uint64_t` is another solution. But what result are you expecting? Multi-byte integers are subject to [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), so do you want the result to be an integer value of `1158005715362648080` (ie `0x1012101010101010`) or a value of `1157442765409227280` (ie `0x1010101010101210`)? They are the same bytes, just in reverse order of each other. `memcpy()` is just a straight byte copy as-is, it doesn't care about data types or endianness.

Comment: You could use plain (bit) arithmetics. Loop over the array, shift value 8 bits to the left, `or` next byte to it, repeat.

Comment: @ca_90 Where are the array bytes coming from in the first place? Do you have any documentation on what the bytes actually represent?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would like to see ie 0x1012101010101010, the first option you proposed

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in a comment:

> I would like to see ie 0x1012101010101010

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/byte>
#include <array>

int main()
{   
  std::array<gsl::byte, 8> gsl_byte_array{{0x10_gslb,0x12_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb, 0x10_gslb}};

  uint64_t int_value{};

  for(auto b : gsl_byte_array) {
    int_value <<= 8;
    int_value |= b;
  }

  std::cout << int_value << "\n"; // prints 1158005715362648080 aka 0x1012101010101010

  return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7i0LFb)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to consider the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (that is how a multibyte integer is interpreted) of your platform and whether or not your code needs to be portable. For this reason, `memcpy` is not a robust solution.

A modern solution might use a template function like the following.

```
#include <bit>
#include <iostream>

template<std::integral T>
auto bytes_to_int(const uint8_t *bytes) {
    T value{};
    if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big) {
        for (auto i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i) {
            value <<= 8;
            value += bytes[i];
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = sizeof(T) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            value <<= 8;
            value += bytes[i];
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

The `boost` library has endianness support for a wide range of platforms.

Many platforms will also have the old-school network byte order functions `htons` and `ntohs` as part of a system library that can accomplish the same tasks, but with a lot less clarity IMO.